# Froala editor formControl not updating after second load

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, froala

When page inited for the first time, everything work fine, when I change pages and then come back to page where Froala editor, writing in editor, form value does not changes

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue too. I stopped using dynamic binding and handled editor changes with froalaEditor.html.get().

Answer (score 0):

In my angular project, I've faced the same issue: the Froala editor form-control only works once or when the page is refreshed not otherwise. So what I've done to fix that is in the editor options set event property like shown below.

```
events: {
      'contentChanged':  ()=> {
        this.emailTemplateForm.value.description = this.editorInstance.html.get(false);
      }
    }
```

**Related issue with work around** - https://github.com/froala/angular-froala-wysiwyg/issues/319